# @capacitor/push-notifications causes Android Studio emulator to crash

Tags: android-studio, capacitor

I'm adding @capacitor/push-notifications to my (Vue) Capacitor project, following the [documentation](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/push-notifications-firebase). The first step in this is the following code:

```
import { PushNotifications } from '@capacitor/push-notifications';
PushNotifications.requestPermissions();
```

However the second line causes my app to crash when I run it in Android Studio's emulator. [Here's a GitHub repo with the code that breaks](https://github.com/tog22/Gods-Vue-Capacitor/tree/3578bcbe28d3b709c436471ddc79230425b564c7), and the [App.vue file within that](https://github.com/tog22/Gods-Vue-Capacitor/blob/3578bcbe28d3b709c436471ddc79230425b564c7/src/App.vue) with the relevant code.

How do I fix this? I seem to be following the simple documentation instructions exactly.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out I hadn't followed [this step in the documentation](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/push-notifications-firebase#download-and-use-the-google-servicesjson-file), downloading the google-services.json and placing it in projectroot/android/app.

Leaving my question here in case it helps others!